# Detect page navigation events in a WP app

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'd like to detect when the app navigates to another page, e.g. triggered by `NavigationService.navigate(uri)`. There is the listener `NavigationService.Navigated`, but since `NavigationService` is a field of one specific page, it's not globally available.

Is there a listener to detect navigation events from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Navigating` event globally in the app.xaml.cs, by using the `RootFrame` property:

```
this.RootFrame.Navigating += this.RootFrame_Navigating;
```

Comment: Great, works! I need to access it from outside (not in a `Page` class). This is possible like that: `PhoneApplicationFrame rootVisual = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;` (and then your code).